# Ejecting from CRA to share components the shared directory are not linted

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I'm experimenting with ejecting from CRA 4 app to enable simple sharing of react components among multiple modules in a monorepo:

```
|-react_project_a
|-react_project_b
|-shared
```

After ejecting, all I had to do is to add the shared module path to two places in the webpack.config file:

```
 new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [
          paths.appPackageJson,
          paths.clientShared //*******here
          reactRefreshOverlayEntry,
        ]),
```

and

```
test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: [paths.appSrc, paths.clientShared],
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader')
```

works a treat, I even get hot reload. The only problem is that only the main app gets linted and so compilation errors and warnings for the shared module appear only in the browser developer tool console, like this:

[image]

The EslintWebpackPlugin used by CRA doesn't support multiple contexts for the plugin.  Is there an alternative?  I'm trying to provide my developers with an experience as close as possible to what they had with CRA.

Comment: Isn't what you have marked in your dev console screenshot a runtime error? That isn't expected to be in your shell. This seems like a linter problem

Comment: They are the same sort of error (me putting some random characters in a javascript file, ss in one case, xxx in the other).

It's the linters job to catch that?  Hmm, you may be onto something.

Comment: You're right on the nose!  When I disable the ESLintPlugin in web pack I get  the same bahavior.  So my question should be can I run the ESLintPlugin  against multiple directories. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since my goal was sharing jsx components among CRA/react apps, the way simpler solution was to create a symbolic link in each react project pointing to the shared directory:

```
|-react_project_a
  |-shared=>shared 
|-react_project_b
  |-shared=>shared
|-shared
```

And to add this to the webpack.config

```
  resolve: {
             symlinks: false
            }
```

Since this was the only change I required, I wound up using [CRACO](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) instead of ejecting to handle the override.  I'd close the question, but think folks might find this useful.